# Using clang tools for adding auto-generated code to source files

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++

I'm working on a logging mechanism for a project, and currently each API function needs to add

```
start_api_call(***)
```

in the beginning of the function
where *** for the function `do_something(int foo, int bar)` is `"foo", foo, "bar",bar`

(The log function takes the parameters and form the desired message)

I would like to make this line auto-generated, where the vision is that somehow (mabye clang tools?) the compiler checks for each function in a .cpp if it is an API function (more details later) and if it is, just add the `start_api_call(***)` to the code.

I have 2 major problems regarding which direction should i go
1) I have never wrote code that it's 'goal' is to parse a source code, hence i don't know which direction should i head, I've read some documentation about the clang tools, but maybe just a python script would be better here?
2) Our design is as follows:

```
object_foo.h //inside .include/
class foo{
API functions
}

object_foo_impl.h //inside .src/
include "object_foo.h"
class foo_impl :foo{
foo API functions
a lot more functions
}

object_foo_impl.cpp
include "object_foo_impl.h"
{
implementation of all foo_impl functions
}
```

The start_api_call should be inserted only for the API functions,
thus i need to find a way to **query** inside the .cpp file, if this function came from the foo.h, or from the foo_impl.h file.

I have a somehow working concept of how to do it using python scripts, that parse all of our source code, identifying using regex which text inside a /include/.h file is a function and then finding all the functions inside .cpp files that implement those functions,
but (if possible) the concept of adding a rule in the compilation(/preprocessor) time is much more attractive.
Any help would be very much appreciated.